# Extending visual studio xml editor with hyperlinks (navigation)

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, editor, vs-extensibility

Is there a way to extend visual studio xml editor with navigation functionality like in C# editor. C# editor (I don't know is this VS or Resharper functionality) allows jumping to another class definition if you press Ctrl and click on class name. I would like to implement something like this in XML editor.
Example:

**file1.xml:**

```
<elements>
    <element elementId="el1" relatedElement="file2.el2" dsDefinition="ds1"/>
</elements>
<datasources>
    <datasource elementId="ds1"/>
</datasources>
```

**file2.xml:**

```
<elements>
    <element elementId="el2"/>
</elements>
```

Clicking on `file2.el2` (while holding ctrl) should open `file2.xml` and position cursor on el2 element. Clickin on ds1 should position cursor to ds1 datasource.

Is this possible using visual studio editor extension mechanisms? If not, are there any other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked same question on msdn forums and got this [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vsx/thread/5fb50b31-af73-423d-adb9-fedcdd2b78e6). It is enough to get me started.